# C# ComboBox DropDownStyle=Simple no working at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Why runtime-created **ComboBox** drop-down is displayed when I put the property **DropDownStyle=Simple**? Is there some other property I miss in order not to show the drop-down?

The code is:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
    cmb.Left = 100;
    cmb.Top = 500;
    cmb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.Simple;
    this.Controls.Add(cmb);
}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: That's what "simple" means.

Comment: It has a different behaviour at design-time, which it works as expected, not showing the dropdown box

Answer (score 1):

The `DropDownStyle` property specifies whether the list is *always* displayed or whether the list is displayed in a drop-down: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Setting it to `Simple` specifices that the list is always visible and that the text portion is editable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle(v=vs.110).aspx.

If you don't want to show the list by default you should set the `DropDownStyle` property to either `DropDown` or `DropDownList` depending on whether you want the text portion to be editable:

```
cmb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
```

Comment: I am asking why it is different from design-time, where the dropdown box is not shown.

Comment: Are you? Did you think that someone would be able to somehow magically figure out that this was your issue without you even mentioning it in your original question?

Comment: @jciberta This is the right answer to what you asked and to be honest, it doesn't matter how it works in design-time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if you don't need to display the drop-down, you don't need a ComboBox.

You can disable your ComboBox setting

```
cmb.IsEnabled = false;
```

or I will use a read-only TextBox or something similar.

Comment: I need the ComboBox for other purposes

Comment: If you specify what "other purposes" means, maybe we can be more usefull.